# How to check conditions in succession?

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, ads

[image: This is what my database looks like ,]

if the first ad block is loaded -> stop checking and execute it -> if the first one is not loaded -> check the second one -> the second one is loaded -> stop checking -> the second one is not loaded -> check the third one .

Tried to execute through Switch case. Only the first block is executed. Please help me figure out what the problem is.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Reklama");
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
    // Switch between video ads and interstitial ads. if Reklama == 1 -> Interstitial / if Reklama == 2 -> Video.
        int Reklama = Math.toIntExact((Long) snapshot.getValue());
        //ad matching cycle
        if (Reklama == 1) {
            final int adUnit1 = 1;
            final int adUnit2 = 2;
            final int adUnit3 = 3;
            int ReklamaInt = 1;
            switch (ReklamaInt) {
                case adUnit1:
                    mInterstitialAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                    break;
                case adUnit2:
                    mInterstitialAdMid.loadAd(adRequest);
                    break;
                case adUnit3:
                    mInterstitialAdLow.loadAd(adRequest);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + ReklamaInt);
            }
        }
        //ad matching cycle
        else if (Reklama == 2) {
            final int adUnit1 = 1;
            final int adUnit2 = 2;
            final int adUnit3 = 3;
            int ReklamaReward = 1;
            switch (ReklamaReward){
                case adUnit1:
                    mRewardedAd.loadAd(adRequest);
                    break;
                case adUnit2:
                    mRewardedAdMid.loadAd(adRequest);
                    break;
                case adUnit3:
                    mRewardedAdLow.loadAd(adRequest);
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Unexpected value: " + ReklamaReward);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

    }
});
```

Comment: Given that the value of `Reklama` in your database is `1`, it seems correct that only the `if (Reklama == 1) {` block is executed. Can you explain what you expected to happen instead?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen "Reklama" - Switch between video ads and interstitial ads. if Reklama == 1 -> Interstitial Displayed / if Reklama == 2 -> Video displayed.

Comment: As @FrankvanPuffelen said, and also you set the variable for your `switch` statements to 1 immediately before the switch so clearly there’s no possibility of the other options ever being executed.

Comment: @racraman, 
My problem is that the first ad is checked and loaded, how can I make sure that all three ads are checked but only one is loaded?
The problem is in : int ReklamaInt = 1;
            switch (ReklamaInt) {

Comment: Nothing in the code you show is about making anything “checked”, so nobody can help you there.   Nor do you show anything that progresses through the sequence, any incrementing of values.   ALL that you show is that you hardcode a value to 1 and then switch on that, so all we can say is “don’t hardcode that value to 1”.  Instead, the switch statements should be controlled by the variables you use to step through the ads.